# image dilation with python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I'm trying to execute a piece of code I found online and it is giving me the following error.
I'm new to opencv so please help me.
error:

```
<ipython-input-1-7fe9c579ec14> in image_masking(filepath)
 15         gray = cv2.imread(filepath,0)
 16         edges = cv2.Canny(gray, CANNY_THRESH_1, CANNY_THRESH_2)
 ---> 17         edges = cv2.dilate(edges,None)
 18         edges = cv2.erode(edges, None)
 19 

 error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv- 
 suite_1533128839831\work\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:760: error: (-215) 
 dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function cv::Mat::locateROI
```

code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def image_masking(filepath):

    BLUR = 21
    CANNY_THRESH_1 = 100
    CANNY_THRESH_2 = 100
    MASK_DILATE_ITER = 10
    MASK_ERODE_ITER = 10
    MASK_COLOR = (0.0,0.0,0.0) # In BGR format

    gray = cv2.imread(filepath,0)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, CANNY_THRESH_1, CANNY_THRESH_2)
    edges = cv2.dilate(edges,None)
    edges = cv2.erode(edges, None)
    contour_info = []
    _, contours, __ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    for c in contours:
        contour_info.append((c, cv2.isContourConvex(c), cv2.contourArea(c),))
     contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True)

     max_contour = contour_info[0]
     for c in contour_info:
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, c[0], (255))
     mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=MASK_DILATE_ITER)
     mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=MASK_ERODE_ITER)
     mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (BLUR, BLUR), 0)

     mask_stack = np.dstack([mask]*3)
     mask_stack  = mask_stack.astype('float32') / 255.0
     img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0

     masked = (mask_stack * img) + ((1-mask_stack) * MASK_COLOR)
     masked = (masked * 255).astype('uint8')

     fileName, fileExtension = filepath.split('.')
     fileName += '-masked.'
     filepath = fileName + fileExtension
     print(filepath)

     cv2.imwrite(filepath, masked)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = 'C:\\Users\HP\Downloads\test3.jpg'
    image_masking(filepath)
```

i tried replacing None in dilate function with kernel but it is giving me the same error

Comment: please copy paste the error (and not a screenshot). also, please add a fully-reproducible code.

Comment: Why are you passing None to the dilate function?

Comment: @api55 if i change it to kernel also it is giving me the same error.please help

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `cv2.dilate` and `cv2.erode` should be the kernel with which you want to perform dilation/erosion as it is shown in the docs: [opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

For example, you can try to do it like that:

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel)
edges = cv2.erode(edges, kernel)
```

Good luck with further opencv exploration!

Comment: if i change it to kernel also it is giving me the same error.please help

Comment: are you sure that the image has been loaded properly?

Comment: are you able to display your image with cv2.imshow('img', gray)?

Comment: yes,it is working but only for some images and i dont understand why it is not working for every image

Comment: maybe this answer can be of use for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564889/opencv-python-not-opening-images-with-imread/24565604#24565604

Comment: if not, please provide the image for which imread doesn't work properly